# linux curl POST request not working

Tags: linux, post, curl

I am trying to make a POST request using curl to retrieve exam results from the page : http://wbutech.net/result_odd.php .... I am using the following syntax but various errors are showing up (like content has moved permanently) although I am using the -L option...
curl -L --data-urlencode "semno=7&rectype=1&rollno=10400111005" http://wbutech.net/show-result.php

can anyone **please post the working syntax** here which works on the above said link correctly and retrieves the results?

(Sample Usage is enter roll as 10400111005 and click semester7 button under regular students...that is what I am trying to do using the above curl syntax)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
curl -XPOST http://wbutech.net/show-result.php -d '{"semno": 7, "rectype": 1, "rollno": 10400111005}'
```

Other than 301/302 redirects, this website requires using credentials, try:

```
curl -u user:passwd -XPOST http://50.28.104.43/show-result.php -d'{"semno": 7, "rectype": 1, "rollno": 10400111005}'
```

replacing `user:passwd` with your *real* username and password.

Comment: Sorry, it didnt work. It says "Moved Permanently"
` <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://115.187.38.236/$">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
`

Comment: On using :
curl -XPOST http://115.187.38.236/show-result.php -d '{"semno": 7, "rectype": 1, "rollno": 10400111005}'
It now says:
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Could Not Connect</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black">
<H1>Could Not Connect</H1>
<HR>

<FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
Description: Could not connect to the requested server host.
</B></FONT>
<HR>
</BODY>

Comment: But, I dont have any userid/passwd !! ... I mean when I access it from the browser I just enter my rollnumber and press semester7 button and it works absolutely fine...

Comment: Running it without creds and you'll get 403 Forbidden. Try it!

Comment: Yes. ( I am bit of a noob...Sorry for bothering you..)
1)But why do I need id/pass when i automate it using script although i dont need id/pass when I access it from my web browser ?
2) Why did you suddenly change the address to http://50.28.104.43/ ?

Comment: 1) when you post it - it redirects  to 50.28.104.43 and 2) ask the guy who wrote this page:  the error message suggests that you can email the error to: ebizindia@gmail.com

Comment: OK.. I will do my research.. but looks like a cookie is also being created 
Cookie : PHPSESSID=75fe2b9fdb199b376e874fa7a3bb0557
from my firefox developer tools